# generic casting from object-boxed type

Tags: c#, generics, casting, boxing, unboxing

Why does this work:

```
decimal dec = new Decimal(33);
double dd = (double) dec;
Console.WriteLine(dd);
```

But not this:

```
decimal dec = new Decimal(33);
object o = (object)dec;
double dd = (double) o;
Console.WriteLine(dd);
```

The second example throws:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

This question comes from a situation where I have a generic method

```
public T GetValue(string q)
```

That gets values from a datasource. The types of these values are unknown, but the method assumes that it can cast the value to T. Sometimes the value will be object{decimal} and T will be double, in which case the InvalidCastException will be thrown. But in principle this should not be an issue since the value is a decimal (albeit boxed by an object) which can be cast to double.

How do I handle this generically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only cast boxed value types back *to the exact type* that was boxed in. It doesn't matter if there is an implicit or explicit conversion from the boxed type to the one you are casting to -- you still have to cast to the boxed type (in order to unbox) and then take it from there.

In the example, this means two consecutive casts:

```
double dd = (double) (decimal) o;
```

Or, using the [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert.aspx) methods:

```
double dd = Convert.ToDouble(o);
```

Of course this won't do for your real use case because you cannot immediately go from a generic type parameter to `ToDouble`. But as long as the target type is `IConvertible`, you can do this:

```
double dd = (double)Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(double));
```

where the generic type parameter `T` can be substituted for `double`.

Answer (score 3):

The latter doesn't work because the decimal value is boxed into an object. That means to get the value back you have to unbox first using the same syntax of **casting**, so you have to do it in 2 steps like this:

```
double dd = (double) (decimal) o;
```

Note that the first `(decimal)` is unboxing, the `(double)` is casting.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `Convert.ChangeType`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal dec = new Decimal(33);
        object o = (object)dec;
        double dd = GetValue<double>(o);
        Console.WriteLine(dd);
    }

    static T GetValue<T>(object val)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

The reason your code doesn't work has been well explained by others on this post.